# Strophejs get roster success callback response

Tags: javascript, xmpp, ejabberd, strophe

I have these functions that allow me to get the roster on ejabberd server.

```
function callback(){
 alert('hi');
}

function getInfo(){

  var iq = $iq({type: 'get'}).c('query', { xmlns: Strophe.NS.ROSTER });
  conn.sendIQ(iq, callback);
}
```

The request is a success since I have an alert. My question is how can I handle the response from the server ? I can see on Wireshark the following response :

```
<body xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/httpbind'>
<iq xmlns='jabber:client'
from='azerty@localhost' to='azerty@localhost/24988088151432746377322003' id='4:sendIQ'
type='result'><query xmlns='jabber:iq:roster'>
<item subscription='both' jid='user1@localhost'><group>EveryBody</group></item>
<item subscription='both' jid='user2@localhost'><group>EveryBody</group></item>
<item subscription='both' jid='user2@localhost'><group>EveryBody</group></item>
</query></iq></body>
```

I would like to get a list with user1, user2, user3.

Any advice on how can I access at least the response like xhr ?

Comment: Please clarify your question. Not sure if you're asking how to handle response or do something with it (ie...what list are you looking for "I would like to get a list with user1, user2, user3."?)

Comment: Sorry, I would like first to get the response. I think I'll be able to pick what I want from it after.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've changed the callback function like this :

```
function callback(iq){
    $(iq).find('item').each(function(){
          var jid = $(this).attr('jid'); 
          alert(jid);
    });
}
```

Works well..

Answer (score 1):

Update your callback function to include the iq.

```
function callback(iq) {
    iq.each(function (o) {
        if (o.subscription === 'both') {
            var jid = Strophe.getNodeFromJid(o.jid);
            //do  whatever
        } else{
           //do something else
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I've trie it but adding an alert(jid) after var jid = Strophe.. doesn't trigger it ?

Comment: I'm guessing you have an error somewhere. Try using console.log instead of alert, or wrapping in a try/catch and alert the error.

Comment: You have a missing semicolon. Although this code doesn't work